# delete i->j if j->i exists?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, filtering

What is a nice way to delete cases of `i -> j` if `j -> i` exists?

It does not matter which one of each pair is deleted as long as one of them is.

#### Input

```
 {1 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}
```

#### Output

```
{1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}
```

---

the application

#### In

```
l = {{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {4 -> 1, 4, 0},  {3 -> 2, 9, 0}, {2 -> 3, 1, 0}}
```

#### Out

```
{{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {2 -> 3, 9, 0}}
```

can this be done a simple way with Pattern Matching?

---

> Thanks for the answers:) I explored [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) in Mathematica.  It finds the maximum flow through a flow network.

[image]

Comment: I think your desired output should be `{4 -> 1, 3 -> 2}` and not `{1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}` ?

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[list, # == Reverse@#2 &]` is the simple way. If list is huge, faster ways to do it...

Comment: After your edits and additions, I'm now befuddled. What is the definition of a "duplicate" here - the second example output is not consistent with that of the first example output. We need to know what kind of *frickin' laser beams* are to be used for the cutting here...

Comment: Sorry! You solved my problem perfectly. `DeleteDuplicates[l, #[[1]] == Reverse@#2[[1]] &]` thank you @ciao

Comment: @ConorCosnett Thank you for accepting my answer despite it being not necessarily the most straight forward one. Do you want to add the [tag:graphs-and-networks]-tag in light of your accepted answer?

Comment: Are you building a graph?  Is it undirected?  If so, use `SimpleGraph`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use `Graph` and friends if your list is small (otherwise this solution does not make much sense regarding both visualization and performance).

```
l = {1 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}
g = Graph[l, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: graph1]

to find cycles of the form $i \rightarrow j \space ,\space j \rightarrow i$ you can use `FindCycle` as in

```
FindCycle[g, 2, All] (* yields {{2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}, {1 -> 4, 4 -> 1}} *)
```

together with `EdgeDelete`

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[g, First /@ FindCycle[g, 2, All]]
```

[image: graph without cycles]

---

A more complex example showcases the visualization benefits of this solution:

**Original graph:**

```
exampleGraph = Graph@Table[RandomInteger[10] -> RandomInteger[10], 20]
```

[image: example graph with cycles]

**Graph with same layout but resolved cycles**

```
Graph[EdgeDelete[exampleGraph, First /@ FindCycle[exampleGraph, 2, All]], 
(exampleGraph //AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates] & // First)]
```

[image: graph without cycles]

**Highlighted cycles in original graph**

```
HighlightGraph[exampleGraph, 
FindCycle[exampleGraph, 2, All], (exampleGraph // AbsoluteOptions[#, VertexCoordinates] & // First)]
```

[image: highlighted graph]

Answer (score 5):

If the order of `i` and `j` does not matter (or if you want them sorted), then the following will work:

```
DeleteDuplicates@ Block[{Rule},
  SetAttributes[Rule, Orderless];
  {1 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}
  ]
(*  {1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}  *)

l = {{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {4 -> 1, 4, 0}, {3 -> 2, 9, 0}, {2 -> 3, 1, 0}};
DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@ Block[{Rule},
  SetAttributes[Rule, Orderless];
  l
  ]
(*  {{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {2 -> 3, 9, 0}}  *)
```

It's probably important that only the list `l` is evaluated inside the `Block`.  One probably does not want to evaluate any built-in functions while `Rule` is `Orderless`.

---

The method above is pretty fast. Some timings:

```
SeedRandom[0];
ll = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[200, {100000, 2}];
DeleteDuplicates@Block[{Rule}, SetAttributes[Rule, Orderless]; ll] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@ll // Length // AbsoluteTiming
Values[GroupBy[ll, Sort, First]] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.084336, 20152}  M e2
  {0.17234, 20152}   kglr
  {0.178762, 20152}  ubpdqn
*)
```

The two-argument `DeleteDuplicates[ll, # == Reverse@#2 &]`, as ciao remarks in a comment, will be a bit slower as the list grow in size (because it uses pairwise comparison that is of quadratic complexity); it takes `0.18` sec. on a list of only 750 rules. Sascha's takes 3+ sec. on the input `ll = Rule @@@ RandomInteger[15, {150, 2}]`, but it is interesting for other reasons.

Comment: thank you got the timing. I have always been 'afraid' of SetAttributes...the eternal lesson of terse not necessarily efficient still not sufficiently penetrated my skull but fun to learn from answers:)

Answer (score 5):

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]@ {1 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}
```

> {1 -> 4, 2 -> 3}

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort@First@#&]@
  {{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {4 -> 1, 4, 0}, {3 -> 2, 9, 0}, {2 -> 3, 1, 0}}
```

or (thanks:  @Michael E2)

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort @* First] @
  {{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {4 -> 1, 4, 0}, {3 -> 2, 9, 0}, {2 -> 3, 1, 0}}
```

> {{1 -> 4, 3, 0}, {3 -> 2, 9, 0}}

Comment: Nice. The second form could be in V10+ `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort @* First]...` or more verbosely in earlier versions `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Composition[Sort, First]]...`.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. Updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

If the order of the rule doesn't matter in output:

```
Values[GroupBy[l, Sort[#[[1]]] &, First]]
```